# Mixing ZeroMQ REQ/REP with C++ 11 futures

Tags: c++, zeromq, future

I'm designing a monitor and control interface manage a number of services. There is a need to have positive feedback and so I would like to use REQ/REP channels to get a response for each request.

However, I'm concerned about the synchronous nature of the channel and the fact that I would need to wait for each request to complete before sending another request. I have read a bit about ROUTER/DEALER pattern and it seems like they would work but it could use some abstraction for my purposes to hide the routing details.

Does it make sense to use C++ 11 futures such that a request could be made that returns a future? In this way, a number of requests could be issued and then await called on the set of futures?

The future would encapsulate the details required to correlate the request with a response.

Has anyone mixed these concepts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Futures will tie your implementation to inproc sockets, as you can't implement a future out of process.

To get any benefit from having concurrent requests, you would need more than one server responding.

Your question is not clear about the topology, you don't explain if you have multiple requesters and one replier, or one requester that can do other work whilst waiting for a reply (including making more requests).  If the later, you'll need a way of matching replies to requests, unless you can guarantee order of processing.

Comment: The future would be for managing the response. The scenario is this: a number of workers are sent a request to which a response is needed. Each request would take some time to fulfil. Each request is made through an abstracted interface where a request like "calculate(X) = Z" returns a "FutureRep<Z>". After all the requests are made some type of "await all" is performed. The FutureRep<T> would encapsulate the details described in XREP/XREQ as part of the ROUTER/DEALER pattern such that the response if properly associated with the request.

Comment: Lets forget the fancy Futures bit and understand what topology you are proposing.

Comment: Each 'worker' is a REQ socket, and the server is a 'REP' socket. One server can only respond in sequence to requests, so to process requests in parallel, you'd need more servers, which suggests a DEALER/ROUTER proxy in the middle to distribute the workload.  You don't need any fancy reply handling to do that.  Each worker just waits for its response.  It could do other work in the meantime, just polling/reading from the socket when it wants the response.

Comment: The requesting end can make multiple parallel requests if it is a DEALER since a DEALER socket has access to the ZMQ socket "identity". So my request is sent asynchronously with many others and the responses are assigned to the correct Future object by inspecting the "identity" field.

Comment: Sorry, you really are being unclear about what you want this to do. REQ/REP is just a formalised, synchronous pattern.  REQ can send, then must receive, REP must receive then send.  Identity is not added by REQ, but a empty delimiter frame is.  REP reads everything up to and including the delimiter, and prepends it to the reply.  ROUTER adds an identity frame to the start of received messages, DEALER distributes to connected peers.

Comment: Dealer breaks the one-to-one relationship with REP, so you must still have multiple REP workers to service multiple requests.  Router breaks the one-to-one relationship with REQ.  So Router allows async requests from one-or-more REQ clients, and Dealer allows async requests to one-or-more REP workers. Still  don't see why you need futures, unless you want to send multiple requests from one client, in which case REQ isn't suitable.  You must then use DEALER (two-way socket) and do any routing yourself at the receiving socket.